# How to compare array a with b and create new arrays c (items in a and b), d (items in a, not in b), and e (items in b, not in a)?

Tags: php

Consider the following arrays. They represent the top-5 performing employees for `yesterday` and `today`:

```
$yesterday = array(
   6 => array('name' => 'Tod', 'score' => 9.5),
  12 => array('name' => 'Jim', 'score' => 7.3),
  18 => array('name' => 'Bob', 'score' => 8.4),
   7 => array('name' => 'Jan', 'score' => 6.2),
  20 => array('name' => 'Sam', 'score' => 6.0),
);

$today = array(
   6 => array('name' => 'Tod', 'score' => 9.1),
   9 => array('name' => 'Jef', 'score' => 9.3),
  35 => array('name' => 'Axl', 'score' => 7.6),
   7 => array('name' => 'Jan', 'score' => 6.5),
  41 => array('name' => 'Ted', 'score' => 8.0),
);
```

I need 3 new arrays compiled from the above: `$stay` holding employees who were in the top-5 yesterday, and still are today, `$gone`, holding employees who were in the top-5 yesterday, but are not anymore, and `$new`, holding newcomers to `$today`s top-5 list:

```
// notice that the scores in $stay come from $today, not $yesterday
// also notice that index keys are maintained

$stay = array(
  6 => array('name' => 'Tod', 'score' => 9.1),
  7 => array('name' => 'Jan', 'score' => 6.5)

);

$gone = array(
  12 => array('name' => 'Jim', 'score' => 7.3),
  18 => array('name' => 'Bob', 'score' => 8.4),
  20 => array('name' => 'Sam', 'score' => 6.0)
);

$new = array(
   9 => array('name' => 'Jef', 'score' => 9.3),
  35 => array('name' => 'Axl', 'score' => 7.6),
  41 => array('name' => 'Ted', 'score' => 8.0)
);
```

I have no clue on how to build the logic here. I started with a loop, but didn't get far. I believe it should be something like this. Could you help me get this right?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($yesterday); $i++) {
  // I'm comparing key numbers, but not key values
  // how do I compare key values?
  if (in_array($yesterday[$i], $today) {
    // add to $stay array
  }
  else {
    // add to $gone array
  }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($today); $i++) {
  if (!in_array($today[$i], $yesterday) {
    // add to $new array
  }
}
```

P.S. I don't know if this is helpfull, but `$yesterday` and `$today` are always of equal length (in this case, 5 items, but other scenarios are possible in which both arrays hold 7 or 10 items for instance). The combined items of `$stay` and `$new` logically are always equal to the number of items in either `$yesterday` or `$today` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using just a few of PHP's many powerful [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php):

```
$stay = array_intersect_assoc($yesterday, $today);
$gone = array_diff_assoc($yesterday, $today);
$new = array_diff_assoc($today, $yesterday);
```

Comment: This comment is intended for the answer by @peter but I lack sufficient rep; it's important to note that array_intersect() and array_diff() are insufficient in the scope of this question as they do not correctly compute *associative* arrays.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-intersect.php
https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-diff.php

```
$c = array_intersect($a, $b);
$d = array_diff($a, $b);
$e = array_diff($b, $a);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work but isnt the fastest method to do this i think.

```
$stay = array();
$gone = array();
$new = array();
$found = false;
foreach($yesterday as $yKey)
{         
  $found = false;
  foreach($today as $tKey)
  {
    if($tKey['name'] == $yKey['name'])
    {
      $found = true;
      $stay[]['name'] = $tKey['name'];  
      break;
    }  
    else
    {
      $found = false;
    }
  }
  if($found == false)
    {
      $gone[]['name'] = $yKey['name'];
    }  
}

foreach($today as $tKey)
{
  $found = false;
  foreach($yesterday as $yKey){
    if($yKey['name'] == $tKey['name'])
    {
      $found = true;
      break;
    }  
    else{
      $found = false;
    }
  }
  if($found == false)
    {
      $gone[]['name'] = $tKey['name'];
    }
}
```